# Cannot compile Python 3.6 with Zlib support

Tags: python, compilation, python-3.6

I am trying to cross-compile Python for a Raspberry Pi 3, but I've been having a lot of issues. For one, it doesn't come with `pip` nor `setuptools` and if I try to install pip via `python3.6 get-pip.py` I get a

> zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

error. Now, I tried to configure it using the `--with-zlib` option but the `configure` script shows a warning that reads

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-zlib

I read A LOT of questions regarding this issue and I double-checked that ALL necessary files are present, I'm on Fedora, and I have installed both `zlib` and `zlib-devel`.

I also have just ran a simple installation (excluding the options and envvars to cross-compile, and using a prefix for the output, so it doesn't mess with my existing installation from the repos) and it also doesn't work, pip and setuptools are not present in site-packages in the output and configure also can't recognize the `--with-` options

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Fedora 26 which has python3.6 in the repos, if that matters for some reason.

Edit: Apparently, I also can't build other packages as well:

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter           
readline              zlib                                     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

I have checked in `setup.py`, specifically for the zlib case and it is apparently ignoring my system's dirs when looking for header files:

```
zlib_inc = find_file('zlib.h', [], inc_dirs)
```

As you can see the arg that should be filled with my system's "standard" paths is empty, If this is a generated file, how can I instruct it to fill it with the beforementioned paths? `--with-zlib-dir=/path` and `--with-zlib=/path` yielded the same results, the `configure` script didn't recognize them.

What is wrong with the process? How can I have Python find and build those packages?

This is a follow-up question for [my question about the installation missing pip and setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47564997/2625090).

Comment: have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Sadly, not yet, I still look into it every other day though